Jitsi Iframe API grantModerator not working when implementing JWT authentication
I'm using the Jitsi Iframe API with JWT authentication for securing the meetings. However, when I try to grant moderator rights using the grantModerator command, nothing happens. I followed the Jitsi documentation and ensured the JWT token I’m sending is correct, but the command doesn't seem to work.
I expected that when a participant joined the room, the grantModerator command would grant them moderator rights, allowing them to control the meeting (mute others, manage settings, etc.).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
